# How to generate Content-Md5 header of post and put request in php

Tags: php, rest

I am building a rest api server and I am trying to send Content-Md5 header in curl request to api server. I am confused on How to calculate md5 hash to send in the request for post and put? We will not need that header for GET and Delete right?

Comment: Content-MD5 has been removed. http://evertpot.com/http-11-updated/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't need to supply the header for any request that does not include a body. This means that in practice, assuming a simple CRUD API, you will only need to worry about it for `PUT` and `POST` requests, `GET` and `DELETE` won't need to include it.

The MD5 hash to include is calculated (in PHP) by passing the request body, in its entirety, through the [`md5()`](http://php.net/md5) function. When using cURL, this means that you must construct the request body as a string manually - you can no long pass an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Lets imagine I want to send the following array to the server:

```
$array = array(
    'thing' => 'stuff',
    'other thing' => 'more stuff'
);
```

If I want to POST it as JSON, I would do something like this:

```
$body = json_encode($array);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($body),
    'Content-MD5: ' . base64_encode(md5($body, true))
));

// ...
```

Similarly if I wanted to send it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, I would just change the [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json-encode) to [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http-build-query) and change the `Content-Type:` header.

Comment: so when doing put request we will simply calculate md5 of the file being sent right?

Comment: Yes, if you are reading the file directly from the file system (for example using `CURLOPT_INFILE`) you can use the PHP function [`md5_file()`](http://php.net/md5-file) to avoid having to read the whole file into memory to calculate the hash.

Comment: thank you very much it was very clear answer

Comment: We will need to base64 encode the md5 return right?

Comment: @askkirati Oh you're right, I've never actually used `Content-MD5` before, I assumed it used the ascii-translated hash, but in fact it uses the base64 encoded binary hash, I have updated the code sample in my answer. You will need to ensure you pass `true` to the second argument of `md5()`/`md5_file()`